# +\ operator in Python

Tags: python, string, operators

What does the +\ operator do in Python?

I came across this piece of code -

```
rows=urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?'+\
's=%s&d=11&e=26&f=2006&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=1996'%t +\
'&ignore=.csv').readlines( )
```

and can't find any references that explain it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `+` is addition. The `\` at the end of the line continues the current statement or expression on the next line.

Comment: Damn you all for beating me to it ;)

Comment: And the funny thing is that the `\\` isn't even necessary in this case.

Comment: This is true. The Python parser can unambiguously determine that the expression must continue on the next line due to the fact that not all "groupings" (parens in this case) have been closed.

Comment: And the funny thing is that the "+" is not even necessary either, as strings that follow each other are automatically concatenated!! (as Dave pointed out)

Comment: It is in this case, due to the placement of the modulus operator.

Comment: There IS a justification for needing it, if you want to be able to copy-and-paste the code into a Python shell.

Comment: As a stylistic practice, the \ line continuation char should be separated by whitespace (for clarity, grep, IDEs, language-sensitive syntax highlighters etc.)

Answer (score 11):

N.B. The `\` continuation is unnecessary in this case since the expression is inside parentheses.  Python is smart enough to know that a line continues until all brackets, braces and parentheses are balanced.

Unnecessary continuation characters are a minor bugbear of mine, and I delete them at every opportunity.  They clutter the code, confuse newbies who think they are some kind of operator and can be invisibly broken by accidentally putting a space after them.

Also the first `+` character is unnecessary - Python will concatenate string literals automatically.

I would also move the % operator to the end of the expression and eliminate the second `+`, so the line could be rewritten as:

```
rows=urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?'
                     's=%s&d=11&e=26&f=2006&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=1996' 
                     '&ignore=.csv' % t).readlines( )
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not an operator, it's just the + operator followed by the line continuation \

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code like so

```
rows=urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?'
                     's=%s&d=11&e=26&f=2006&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=1996'
                     '&ignore=.csv'%t).readlines()
```

The parser joins the lines together into one, so you are not wasting time by uselessly adding strings together at runtime